# Render control into image in WinRT metro

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, rendering, windows-runtime

I'm creating an application for windows 8 metro, I need to render a framework control into an image and save it to hard disk but do not know how. Can I use SharpDX for this? How can I do? Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: There is a extension method for that in winrt xaml toolkit. http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/512f5e79e2b6#WinRTXamlToolkit.Composition/WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow through [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/63dd9596-bf94-440b-847a-961cbf036e7b) thread the limitations of Metro and the reasons why it won't work are explained.  The essence of it is:

> Sorry, but rendering Xaml to an element or capturing a screenshot of
>   your own app did not make it into the release version. It is by design
>   that an app cannot capturing a screenshot of another app.

A workaround mentioned is:

> What I meant was - you can draw shapes, text and images using
>   Direct2D. The same shapes that you would otherwise draw with XAML UI.
>   I did not mean to imply that you can render XAML controls - just that
>   you can use Direct2D as an alternative to achieve same results albeit
>   with somewhat more effort.

Answer (score 3):

justin.m.chase's approach certainly works if you do not mind adding dependencies to SharpDX assemblies.  The RenderTargetBitmap class might be a good fit for what you are trying to accomplish.

```
// Render XAML to bitmap
var bitmap = new  RenderTargetBitmap();
await bitmap.RenderAsync(elementToRender);

// get the pixels
IBuffer pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
byte[] pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();

// write the pixels to a InMemoryRandomAccessStream
var stream = new  InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, stream);
encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96, pixels);

await encoder.FlushAsync();
stream.Seek(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I apologize that this is not possible. The WritableBitmap class' Render() method is current insufficient to accomplish what you are wanting. For the same reason a screenshot cannot be created at this time. But these are the things that are on the backlog! But, now you know.

Answer (score 1):

Because I think this is a more correct answer I would like to reiterate the comment that [Zeeshan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483248/zeeshan) made in the original question.

> There is a extension method for that in winrt xaml toolkit. 
>   [http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/.../WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.cs](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/512f5e79e2b6#WinRTXamlToolkit.Composition/WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.cs)

Install via nuget:

```
> Install-Package WinRTXamlToolkit.Composition
```

Add the using:

```
using WinRTXamlToolkit.Composition;
```

Render your xaml:

```
var bitmap = await element.Render();
```