# WinRT UI-elements rendering

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, writeablebitmap

There is a need to make the picture from a UI element (WriteableBitmap or something similar).
At Windows Phone this problem is solving by this way:

```
var frameworkElement = new Button();
.....
var wrb = new WriteableBitmap(frameworkElement, null);
```

There is no the such constructor overload of WriteableBitmap at Windows 8.

Is there a similar way to solve this problem for Windows 8?

Comment: I tried to find a solution too: It seems that there is no way to do this in WinRT at the moment (maybe with Win8.1)

Comment: Currently not possible...

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640855/render-control-into-image-in-winrt-metro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only available in windows 8.1

http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.com/2013/06/windows-81-rendertargetbitmap.html